# Dataframe operations with nan: dtype not working, vectorize problems

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I frequently have dataframes that are missing an ID like so:

```
     ID Price
0  1000   900
1  1001   100
2  1002   150
3   NaN   600
```

I'll want to apply some kind of logic to the ID to determine if the record is special, to get this kind of an output:

```
     ID Price  Special ID?
0  1000   900        False
1  1001   100        False
2  1002   150         True
3   nan   600        False
```

I typically

1. Try to take in the dataframe as string*
2. Apply a function using numpy `vectorize`

However, I've been running into unexpected behavior.

1. I specify `dtype=str` while taking in the data. <- **should be enough**
2. I'll still receive a ValueError indicating the input is being read as a float with `vectorize`.
3. I have to convert the column again with `astype(str)`. <- **extra step that shouldn't be needed?** **

I have a guess as to what's happening*** but I first wanted to hear from others.

Code you can run below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# My data comes in with some empty IDs, but these rows are still usable.
data_with_nan = {'ID':['1000','1001','1002', np.nan],
                 'Price':['900','100','150', '600']}

# I set dtype to str.
df_with_nan = pd.DataFrame(data_with_nan,dtype=str)

# My console tells me that the ID column is 'object'. I interpret this to mean the
# column only contains objects (which apparently is pandas' shorthand for string). 
#Seems to have worked.
df_with_nan.dtypes

def special_id(id):
    """Identify IDs that have 2 in them"""
    # I assume that using the dtype of str converts np.nan to 'NaN'.
    if '2' in id:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df_with_nan['Special IDs'] = np.vectorize(special_id)(df_with_nan['ID'])
# However, this assumption was incorrect:
# TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

# Maybe I can use an if condition to check if the argument is none?
def special_id_with_check(id):
    """Identify IDs that have 2 in them"""
    if id:
        if '2' in id:
            return True

df_with_nan['Special ID?'] = np.vectorize(special_id_with_check)(df_with_nan['ID'])
# This continues to return the same error:
# TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

# Therefore, I must explicitly cast this column as string (even though specifying dtype
# should have done this for me?)
df_with_nan['ID'] = df_with_nan['ID'].astype(str)

df_with_nan
df_with_nan['Special ID?'] = np.vectorize(special_id)(df_with_nan['ID'])
# Now it works.
```

*My understanding is that nan comes in as a float, so to import the dataframe as a float would continue to make the nans problematic. I expect when I take in a dataframe as string for nan to become 'NaN'

**You might ask, "well why not have your function check if the input is null?" I have, but somehow I still receive a ValueError when using `vectorize`.

***My guess is that what's happening is that dtype only converts non-null values. In which case, what I really should be doing is leaving dtype out, then convert to string at the last minute in my function call like so -

`df_with_nan['Special ID?'] = np.vectorize(special_id)(df_with_nan['ID'].astype(str))`

This approach strikes me as rather strange. I'd rather get all the type stuff out of the way upfront.

Comment: Despite the fancy name, according to [the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), `np.vectorize` is just a `for` loop.

Comment: `pandas` uses object dtype for columns that contain strings.  It doesn't use `numpy` string dtypes.  Object columns can also contain numbers, `nan` (float), etc.

Answer (score 0):

`np.nan` type is float, so 'ID' column contains both floats and strings. As mentioned in the first comment you should try to avoid using vectorize, you can simply do

```
df_with_nan['Special ID?'] = pd.isnull(df_with_nan['ID'])
```

no conversion is necessary.

As a side note, you can check actual type of the value by running `type(df_with_nan['ID'][row_idx])` where `row_idx` is integer row index, it will be `str` for what you call non-special ID and `float` for special ID.